# how does Context struct work in golang gin framework?

Tags: function, go, web, input

I want to understand what is Context in go gin , i see a lot of functions written which accept context as a parameter but dont see it passed anywhere or instantiated anywhere ? , can someone explain how it works

Answer (score 5):

The gin Context is a structure that contains both the http.Request and the http.Response that a normal http.Handler would use, plus some useful methods and shortcuts to manipulate those.

The gin engine is responsible for the creation (and reuse) of those contexts, in the same manner as the http.Server is responsible for the creation of the http.Request objects a standard http.Handler would use.

The context is passed by the engine to its handlers, and it's your job to write those handlers and attach them to a router. A gin handler is any function that takes a gin.Context as its sole argument and doesn't return anything.

Comment: I would add to what Olivier mentions that the Context is meant to be a routine safe resource to work with request/response data on every layer of your app. You can read more about the reasons for its existence in [this article](https://golangbyexample.com/using-context-in-golang-complete-guide/)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by routine safe. In any case, it is not goroutine safe. The documentation explicitely says to not pass a gin Context to a goroutine, but to pass a copy instead using the Copy() method.